# python Unable to send email using my gmail when VPN is on

Tags: python, email, gmail, vpn

[image]I have written python code to send an email, it is working fine but when I am using VPN it does not send an email and give an error,
I need **VPN** ON because I am scraping a website with VPN and when the scraper script ends I send scraped data using email
please let me know the solution
Thanks

Comment: It might help to show the error you are seeing

Comment: done, please check